# Cannot Login User when Using Selenium with Rails/RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I am running tests that starts by logging in a user using the login form. It successfully opens Firefox, navigates to the login form and fills in the fields, but when it clicks the 'Login' button, it hangs indefinitely. When I quit Firefox the test that was running fails, but I am not getting any additional error message.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? This is driving me crazy and preventing me from testing a big portion of my app, any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Here is some additional info:

- Rails 4.2.0
- Ruby 2.2.4
- Capybara 2.6.2
- Selenium-Webdriver 2.53.0
- Firefox 46.0.1
- Using Capybara with RSpec
- `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium`

**/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However,
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.

  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'

  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'aasm/rspec'

  RSpec.configure do |config|

    config.include Capybara::DSL

    def test_sign_in(user)
      # helper method to sign in the passed-in user
      visit new_user_session_path
      within ('#user-login-non-modal') do
          within(".user-login") do
            fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
            fill_in 'Password', with: 'foobar11'
            click_button 'Sign in'
          end
        end
    end

    def test_partner_sign_in(partner)
      # helper method to sign in the passed-in partner
      visit new_partner_session_path
      within('#partner-login-non-modal') do
          within(".partner-login") do
            fill_in 'Email', with: partner.email
            fill_in 'Password', with: 'foobar11'
            click_button 'Sign in'
          end
        end
    end

    # configure database cleaner
    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    end

    config.before(:each, js: true) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
      expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
    end

    config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
      mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
    end

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  # if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
  #   config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  # end

  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

**/rails_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate 

rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'
require 'controller_macros'
require 'byebug'

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller


  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

**/test.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.serve_static_files  = true
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # For Devise
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

**.rspec**

```
--color
--require spec_helper
--drb
```

**Edit:**

**user_pages_spec.rb**

```
describe "show page" do
    before do
        # @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        @user = User.invite!(:email => "test_user@example.com", :skip_invitation => true)
        @user.accept_invitation!
        @user.password = "foobar11"
        @user.first_name = "John"
        @user.last_name = "Smith"
        @user.save
        @car1 = FactoryGirl.create(:car, user: @user)
        @car2 = FactoryGirl.create(:car, user: @user)

        @tomorrow = Time.now + 24*60*60
        @earlier_today = Time.now - 30

        @app_in_future1 = FactoryGirl.create(:appointment, car: @car1, garage: @car1.garage, pickuptime: @tomorrow)
        @app_in_future2 = FactoryGirl.create(:appointment, car: @car1, garage: @car1.garage, pickuptime: @tomorrow + 24*60*60)
        @app_in_past = FactoryGirl.build(:appointment, car: @car1, garage: @car1.garage, pickuptime: @earlier_today)
        @app_in_past.save(validate: false)

        different_pickup_time = @tomorrow + 60*60
        @different_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        @car_different_user = FactoryGirl.create(:car, make: "diff_make", user: @different_user)
        @app_different_user = FactoryGirl.create(:appointment, car: @car_different_user, garage: @car_different_user.garage, pickuptime: different_pickup_time)

        test_sign_in(@user)
    end
describe "adding an appointment to a car", js:true do
    context "when the appointment is in the future" do
        it "should increment the number of the car's appointments" do
            expect do
                within(".create-appt-row-#{@car1.id}") do
                    click_button 'Add Appointment'
                  fill_in 'appointment_pickuptime', with: "12/07/2100 4:57 PM"
                  click_button 'Book It'
                end
            end.to change(@car1.appointments, :count).by(1)
        end
    end
end
```

**Edit 3:**

After updating to `selenium-webdriver 2.53.4` and re-running the test that requires the user-login, Firefox is hanging indefinitely, and when I quit Firefox manually I get this error message with the failing test:

```
      Failure/Error: visit new_user_session_path

      Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
        Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 7055
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `response_for'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:58:in `request'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:134:in `get'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:33:in `to'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:45:in `visit'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:232:in `visit'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
      # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:23:in `test_sign_in'
      # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/spork-224df492657e/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:12:in `run_tests'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/spork-224df492657e/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/spork-224df492657e/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/spork-224df492657e/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/spork-224df492657e/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/spork-224df492657e/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/spork-224df492657e/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
      # /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/spork-224df492657e/lib/spork/server.rb:49:in `run'
```

**Edit 4:**

**test.log after running the test that hangs**

```
[1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (1.7ms)[0m  [1mALTER TABLE "active_admin_comments" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "authorizations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "authorized_drivers" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "garagepartners" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "locations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "partners" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "appointments" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "images" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "garages" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "users" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "companies" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "damages" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "admin_users" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "delayed_jobs" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL[0m
  [1m[35m (2.3ms)[0m            SELECT schemaname || '.' || tablename
          FROM pg_tables
          WHERE
            tablename !~ '_prt_' AND
            tablename <> 'schema_migrations' AND
            schemaname = ANY (current_schemas(false))

  [1m[36m (2.0ms)[0m  [1mselect table_name from information_schema.views where table_schema = 'parkme3_test'[0m
  [1m[35m (55.4ms)[0m  TRUNCATE TABLE "public"."active_admin_comments", "public"."authorizations", "public"."authorized_drivers", "public"."garagepartners", "public"."cars", "public"."locations", "public"."partners", "public"."appointments", "public"."images", "public"."garages", "public"."users", "public"."companies", "public"."damages", "public"."admin_users", "public"."delayed_jobs" RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
  [1m[36m (0.9ms)[0m  [1mALTER TABLE "active_admin_comments" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "authorizations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "authorized_drivers" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "garagepartners" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "locations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "partners" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "appointments" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "images" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "garages" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "users" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "companies" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "damages" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "admin_users" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "delayed_jobs" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.4ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "test_user@example.com"]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."invitation_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["invitation_token", "12f7e3e1ca7f4be3bf7ebc51410444e1b49d703cade994df75ca75a2e49fed3e"]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "users" ("receive_email_notification", "receive_text_notification", "email", "encrypted_password", "invitation_token", "invitation_created_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["receive_email_notification", "t"], ["receive_text_notification", "t"], ["email", "test_user@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$04$dzJj7097jsrmaWOfVGqrq.F4wcKx4yktACtDVjI7IXbt6u83C7.QO"], ["invitation_token", "12f7e3e1ca7f4be3bf7ebc51410444e1b49d703cade994df75ca75a2e49fed3e"], ["invitation_created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.921974"], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.923749"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.923749"]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "invitation_accepted_at" = $1, "invitation_token" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["invitation_accepted_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.929347"], ["invitation_token", nil], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.930593"], ["id", 1]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "encrypted_password" = $1, "first_name" = $2, "last_name" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5[0m  [["encrypted_password", "$2a$04$c8LSFWcTJXE7np2W838iLui3lHt7yYXSjQvhQoxt91EqkW1xvBr1q"], ["first_name", "John"], ["last_name", "Smith"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.938120"], ["id", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "min_time_in_minutes", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "company_1"], ["min_time_in_minutes", 15], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.977122"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.977122"]]
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "garages" ("name", "time_zone", "min_time_in_minutes", "urgent_minutes", "use_acknowledgement", "use_locations", "use_damage_tracking", "use_numpad_make_appointment_form", "phone_number", "company_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["name", "garage_1"], ["time_zone", "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"], ["min_time_in_minutes", 15], ["urgent_minutes", 60], ["use_acknowledgement", "t"], ["use_locations", "t"], ["use_damage_tracking", "t"], ["use_numpad_make_appointment_form", "f"], ["phone_number", "7777777777"], ["company_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.982258"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.982258"]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "cars" ("make", "car_model", "year", "car_number", "garage_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["make", "make_1"], ["car_model", "car_model_1"], ["year", 2014], ["car_number", 1], ["garage_id", 1], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.988597"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.988597"]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "min_time_in_minutes", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["name", "company_2"], ["min_time_in_minutes", 15], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.996186"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.996186"]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "garages" ("name", "time_zone", "min_time_in_minutes", "urgent_minutes", "use_acknowledgement", "use_locations", "use_damage_tracking", "use_numpad_make_appointment_form", "phone_number", "company_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "garage_2"], ["time_zone", "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"], ["min_time_in_minutes", 15], ["urgent_minutes", 60], ["use_acknowledgement", "t"], ["use_locations", "t"], ["use_damage_tracking", "t"], ["use_numpad_make_appointment_form", "f"], ["phone_number", "7777777777"], ["company_id", 2], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.999804"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:23.999804"]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "cars" ("make", "car_model", "year", "car_number", "garage_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["make", "make_2"], ["car_model", "car_model_2"], ["year", 2014], ["car_number", 2], ["garage_id", 2], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.003820"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.003820"]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "appointments" ("aasm_state", "pickuptime", "car_id", "garage_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["aasm_state", "scheduled"], ["pickuptime", "2016-07-16 15:02:24.006227"], ["car_id", 1], ["garage_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.026603"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.026603"]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "appointments" ("aasm_state", "pickuptime", "car_id", "garage_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["aasm_state", "scheduled"], ["pickuptime", "2016-07-17 15:02:24.006227"], ["car_id", 1], ["garage_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.033088"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.033088"]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "appointments" ("aasm_state", "pickuptime", "car_id", "garage_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["aasm_state", "scheduled"], ["pickuptime", "2016-07-15 15:01:54.006233"], ["car_id", 1], ["garage_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.039517"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.039517"]]
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'person_1@example.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("receive_email_notification", "receive_text_notification", "email", "encrypted_password", "invitation_accepted_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["receive_email_notification", "t"], ["receive_text_notification", "t"], ["email", "person_1@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$04$glYjOuWxkRp06jc/l1X0ceeI5OD.eqWMzsnt/MRhizfX7RuD7ti9m"], ["invitation_accepted_at", "2016-07-15 14:02:24.045381"], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.053170"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.053170"]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "min_time_in_minutes", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["name", "company_3"], ["min_time_in_minutes", 15], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.060156"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.060156"]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "garages" ("name", "time_zone", "min_time_in_minutes", "urgent_minutes", "use_acknowledgement", "use_locations", "use_damage_tracking", "use_numpad_make_appointment_form", "phone_number", "company_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "garage_3"], ["time_zone", "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"], ["min_time_in_minutes", 15], ["urgent_minutes", 60], ["use_acknowledgement", "t"], ["use_locations", "t"], ["use_damage_tracking", "t"], ["use_numpad_make_appointment_form", "f"], ["phone_number", "7777777777"], ["company_id", 3], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.063107"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.063107"]]
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "cars" ("make", "car_model", "year", "car_number", "garage_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["make", "diff_make"], ["car_model", "car_model_3"], ["year", 2014], ["car_number", 3], ["garage_id", 3], ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.066940"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.066940"]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "appointments" ("aasm_state", "pickuptime", "car_id", "garage_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["aasm_state", "scheduled"], ["pickuptime", "2016-07-16 16:02:24.006227"], ["car_id", 3], ["garage_id", 3], ["created_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.071953"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-15 15:02:24.071953"]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-15 11:02:26 -0400
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/sessions/_new.html.erb (75.4ms)
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (82.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered users/sessions/_new.html.erb (8.2ms)
  Rendered partners/sessions/_new.html.erb (16.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (27.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 206ms (Views: 190.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-15 11:02:28 -0400
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"test_user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

This is where it hung. The rest of the log appeared after the test timed out.

```
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  ALTER TABLE "active_admin_comments" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "authorizations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "authorized_drivers" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "garagepartners" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "locations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "partners" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "appointments" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "images" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "garages" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "users" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "companies" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "damages" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "admin_users" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "delayed_jobs" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
  [1m[36m (45.9ms)[0m  [1mTRUNCATE TABLE "public"."active_admin_comments", "public"."authorizations", "public"."authorized_drivers", "public"."garagepartners", "public"."cars", "public"."locations", "public"."partners", "public"."appointments", "public"."images", "public"."garages", "public"."users", "public"."companies", "public"."damages", "public"."admin_users", "public"."delayed_jobs" RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;[0m
  [1m[35m (0.8ms)[0m  ALTER TABLE "active_admin_comments" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "authorizations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "authorized_drivers" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "garagepartners" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "locations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "partners" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "appointments" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "images" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "garages" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "users" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "companies" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "damages" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "admin_users" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "delayed_jobs" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

This was in the Spork console after the test timed out:

```
1.1) Failure/Error: click_button 'Sign in'

          Net::ReadTimeout:
            Net::ReadTimeout
```

**users/sessions_controller.rb (using Devise)**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include ApplicationHelper

  def create
    super
  end

  def new
    render 'new'
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path(resource)
  end
end
```

Got stuck at this point when stepping through the controller using `byebug`:

```
in /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/devise-3.5.6/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
   12:     respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
   13:   end
   14: 
   15:   # POST /resource/sign_in
   16:   def create
=> 17:     self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
```

After stepping into that, I got stuck here:

```
in /Users/JAckerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/proxy.rb
   122:     # Example
   123:     #   env['warden'].authenticate!(:password, :scope => :publisher) # throws if it cannot authenticate
   124:     #
   125:     # :api: public
   126:     def authenticate!(*args)
=> 127:       user, opts = _perform_authentication(*args)
   128:       throw(:warden, opts) unless user
   129:       user
   130:     end
```

Comment: how long does your program hang?

Comment: Please show the code for an actual test that hangs - Does your login process happen to make another API call back to the same app?  Also check for leftover debugging (binding.pry, byebug, etc) in your code.   On a side note - your `config.after(:each) do DatabaseCleaner.clean  end` should actually be `config.append_after(:each) do ...` to make sure the DB clean doesn't happen until after the sessions have been reset (you should probably update to capybara 2.7.1 too for similar reasons)

Comment: @YuZhang, it hangs indefinitely until I quit Firefox

Comment: @TomWalpole, I've added the test causing it to hang and the code that runs before the test. The `test_sign_in(@user)` function that is called is referring to a function in `spec_helper.rb`, and it is working (the login page is visited, the form is populated, and the button is clicked), but then it just keeps loading the page indefinitely. Thanks!

Comment: I updated Firefox, and I am now seeing a new error message, which I've included above. Thanks

Comment: @jackerman09 to use Firefox 47.0.1 you need to update to the latest selenium-webdriver (2.53.4 IIRC)

Comment: @jackerman09 Did you check for leftover debugging statements? and what action is triggered by the `click_button 'Sign in'` - does it make a call to another API endpoint in your app? - Please answer all the questions otherwise I can't help you - Also I would expect your test to fail as written  since `click_button 'Book It'` gets executed asynchronously, so the expect to change will get evaluated before the button click has been processed.  You would need to add `expect(page).to have 'Appointement Booked!'` or whatever is appropriate after the `click_button` to make sure it's completed

Comment: @TomWalpole, thank you for the feedback! I will update my selenium-webdriver to 2.53.4 and see if that helps. `The click_button 'Sign in'` action is a form that is submitted to `sessions#create` to create the user session (I am using Devise for authentication). I did check for leftover debugging statements (both in development and in the tests), and this sign-in works fine outside of testing. I am not really worried about the test failing at this point, I am just trying to get the user signed in, then I will worry about the specific tests. Thanks again!

Comment: @TomWalpole, updating selenium-webdriver to 2.53.4 got Firefox to go to the login page, however, I am back to having the original issue of the browser hanging after the sign-in button is clicked. Thanks!

Comment: What does your test.log show?

Comment: Also, looking at the log I see that this test is a request spec -- Capybara hasn't supported request specs by default since v2 - which is why you've had to include the Capybara::DSL manually - Capybara is usually only used with feature specs (and the matchers with view specs) - I don't think that would cause the current issue you're having, but it wouldn't hurt to try

Comment: Does the 'click_button' method return and then it hangs, or does it hang, never returning from that method?  Does the next page load?  Or is it still on the sign-in page? If it is still on the sign-in page, does it have a loading indicator like it is waiting for something to load?  You might try issuing a javascript click to see if that works, not sure exactly how to do that with capybara since I don't use it.

Comment: @TomWalpole, I've added the `test.log` file. The test hangs after the `POST` request to `/login`, and the rest of the log appeared after the test timed out and Firefox quit. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: @SamWoods, per the `test.log` file (which I've added above), the `POST` request is made, and that is where it hangs. The next page does not load, it stays on the sign-in page until it times out. It does have the loading indicator the whole time. I will try that, thanks!

Comment: @jackerman09 ok from that log it appears the Users::SessionsController#create action is hanging - what code is there?

Comment: @TomWalpole, I've added the code. I am using Devise, and the only change I made to the default controller is to customize the redirect after signin using the `after_sign_in_path_for` callback. I don't see why that would behave differently in a test as compared to in development/production.

Comment: @SamWoods, I tried using a JS click and had the same result, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @jackerman09 Have you changed the number of stretches in the devise config? If so what's it set to in test mode?

Comment: @TomWalpole, I have not intentionally changed this, as I'm not even sure what stretches are. But this is the code in `devise.rb`: `config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10`

Comment: @jackerman09 - sorry I'm out of guesses, only thing left to suggest would be to use byebug and step through the session create method to see where it's hanging.  I'm assuming this code isn't publically accessible? If it is I'll take a look

Comment: @TomWalpole Ok, thanks for all of the help, if I ever get this figured out I'll be sure to post an answer here. The code's not publicly available, but thanks for the offer!

Comment: @jackerman09 One last guess :)  You're not attempting to use connection sharing between the test and app thread like https://gist.github.com/josevalim/470808 are you?

Comment: @TomWalpole No, I've never come across that before, thanks though

Comment: @jackerman09 oh well -- then try byebug and stepping through the controller action and/or removing spork -- best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling out a lot of hair, this is what ended up working:

Change:

```
# configure database cleaner
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end
```

To:

```
# configure database cleaner
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end
```

And add `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` to `rails_helper.rb`, which had been there at the beginning and had been removed at some point in the many iterations of configurations that I had tried.

Either way, hopefully this saves someone else a headache!